# ASP.NET Upload file control and showing wait message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I've already searched the internet and try different approaches but I'm having a really hard time to make it work. I'll accept any help, involving third parts components, javascript and everything...
My problem (I think) is that I'm not using an Upload button but a button that also save a data form.
Markup:

```
<div id="divInserimento" runat="server" class="contact-form scrollDiv">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitolo" placeholder="Titolo nota" CssClass="input_text" MaxLength="1000"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNota" placeholder="Nota" CssClass="input_text" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="10em"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 3px; background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid black;">
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="MyFileUpload" Width="100%" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnNomeFile" />
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="gbutton" ID="btnAnnullaIns" Text="Annulla" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnAnnullaIns_Click" />
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="gbutton" ID="btnConfermaIns" Text="Conferma" OnClick="btnConfermaIns_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
Function Upload()
        Dim file As String = ""
        If MyFileUpload.HasFile Then
            If MyFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 15000000 Then

                'throbber.Style("display") = "normal"
                Dim path As String = My.Settings.pathUpload1 & rfCliente & My.Settings.pathUpload2
                If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then
                    'If Directory (Folder) does not exists. Create it.
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
                End If

                file = path & MyFileUpload.FileName

                MyFileUpload.SaveAs(file)
                hdnNomeFile.Value = file
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Scriptkey", String.Format("alert('{0}');", "File caricato: " & MyFileUpload.FileName), True)

                If MyFileUpload.FileName.Contains(".txt") Then
                    Dim srRead As New System.IO.StreamReader(file)
                    Dim strFileText As String = ""
                    strFileText = srRead.ReadToEnd
                    srRead.Close()
                    txtNota.Text = strFileText
                    txtTitolo.Text = MyFileUpload.FileName
                End If
                Return True
            Else
                hdnNomeFile.Value = ""
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Scriptkey", String.Format("alert('{0}');", "Errore nel caricamento"), True)
                Return False
            End If
            'throbber.Style("display") = "none"

        Else
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Scriptkey", String.Format("alert('{0}');", "Il file supera le dimensioni massime consentite (15mb)"), True)
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

The function "Upload" is called by pressing the btnConfermaIns button as follow:

```
If MyFileUpload.HasFile Then
                If Upload() Then
                    inserimentoNota()
                Else
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Scriptkey", String.Format("alert('{0}');", "Errore nel caricamento"), True)
                End If
            Else
                inserimentoNota()
            End If
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to show a "wait" message while the file is uploading.

You can accomplish this using javascript:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="gbutton" ID="btnConfermaIns" Text="Conferma" OnClick="btnConfermaIns_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="showWaitingMessage()" />
<div id="waitMessage" style="display: none;">Please wait...</div>
<script>
     function showWaitingMessage() {
          document.getElementById("waitMessage").style.display = "block";
     }
</script>
```

Comment: so simple! I tried everything except this! Thank you